# SQL 2008 Full Text Search from Classic ASP?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic, full-text-search

I have a legacy app in which I need to enable search.

Recently we've switched to SQL 2008 and I was wondering to do it with it's Full Text Search.

However my question is...is there API available for Classic ASP? Any references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think full text search is a completly service side feature and that you only send normal SQL queries in which case normal ADODB should be sufficent to use it.

But I have never tried fulltext service my self so I am not a 100 % sure.

Comment: Went searching and it is...thnx! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Full text search features of the SQL server. Create a stored procedure uisng Free text searh indexing features(Use contains & Free text keywords in SQL query).
You need create Index and catelog for your database.

Call the stored procedure from classic ASP.